# How to change "Devise: password reset instruction email's subject"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, mailer

I'm just unable to change "password reset instruction" email's subject. I have changed notifer.rb in Mailer to overwrite Devise default email subject. But it's not working.

Here in my application there is default Email subject inside Devise .yml file. But I want to make it dynamic to change it by pulling data from DB.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

you can change it in devise.en.yml file in intilizer directory

And set your own subject for any mailer

```
                   mailer:
                     confirmation_instructions:
                       subject: 'Confirmation instructions'
                     reset_password_instructions:
                       subject: 'Reset password instructions'
                     unlock_instructions:
                       subject: 'Unlock Instructions'
```

Comment: `config/locales` directory?

Comment: `config/locales/devise.en.yml`

Comment: You should have a path `en.devise.mailer.confirmation_instructions.subject` https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/main/lib/devise/mailers/helpers.rb#L70

Answer (score 19):

I got this to work by creating my own sub-class of Devise::Mailer.

```
class DeviseMailer < Devise::Mailer
  def reset_password_instructions(record, token, opts={})
    mail = super
    # your custom logic
    mail.subject = "[SOME DB DATA]"
    mail
  end
end
```

And then modifying the devise.rb initializer to use my mailer.

```
# Configure the class responsible to send e-mails.
config.mailer = 'DeviseMailer'
```

Comment: as of today, the only example that works well. thanks

Comment: Still the way to go in 2020

Answer (score 6):

Change option `:subject`:

```
class DeviseMailer < Devise::Mailer
  def reset_password_instructions(record, token, opts={})
    opts[:subject] = 'SOME DB DATA'
    super
  end
end
```

Comment: This is a great one answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own method inside your controller and call the respective mailer template. This will help you.. Else devise views, there will be a view page to send reset instruction. Change the content there..

Comment: I already tried to to pull data from DB to view page (inside devise), and it's not working, it's throwing an error "undefined method"

Answer (score 1):

For default foreign language (example Japanese)

**STEP 1** Create a 'ja.yml' in config/locales/ (or whatever filename)

```
ja:
  devise:    
    mailer:
      confirmation_instructions:
        subject: '仮会員登録完了のお知らせ'
      reset_password_instructions:
        subject: 'パスワード再設定手順のお知らせ'
```

**STEP 2** On config/environments/development.rb

```
config.i18n.default_locale = :ja
```

**STEP 3** Restart server

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to translate your Devise messages, which was my case, a better practice would be creating a new yml file in `config/locale` and changing your application's locale at `config/application.rb`

1. To illustrate, I had to create `devise.pt-BR.yml` inside `config/locale`.
2. Then I copied its translations from internet, on [this link](https://gist.github.com/mateusg/924555/).
3. Finally, I set my application's new locale at `config/application.rb` as follows:

   ```
   config.i18n.default_locale = :'pt-BR'
   ```

Hope it helps some of you guys having the same problem as mine.

Answer (score 0):

it worked for me to add the translation in devise.en.yml, but the right key for reset_password_instructions was user_subject instead of subject

```
  en:
    devise:
      mailer:
        reset_password_instructions:
          user_subject: Reset password instructions
```