# Add dynamic value in devise email subject

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-confirmable

Ok I have seen many discussions about customizing devise email subject but none seems to solve what I want. Currently my confirmation email subject reads "**Confirm your Qitch.com account**". I want to customize this email subject and add a dynamic value of a user's name in it such that if user **ALEX** signs up for an account, he should get an email address with the subject, **Welcome ALEX, confirm your Qitch.com account**. How can I achieve this in devise?

`devise.en.yml`

```
mailer:
  confirmation_instructions:
    subject: 'Confirm your Qitch.com account'
  reset_password_instructions:
    subject: 'Reset your Qitch.com password'
  unlock_instructions:
    subject: 'Unlock your Qitch.com account'
```

Lastly, how do I add a name in the reply address or from address, currently when you receive the mail, it says sender: `no-reply@qitch.com` Is there a way I can customize it to `Qitch`

Thanks

Comment: As of 23.10.2014, this will be a better solution as it might be the simplest one, on top of that is does work http://stackoverflow.com/a/21344142/102133

Answer (score 15):

I see that no answers are clean enough so I would like to make a short summary here.

1. First of all, you have to tell `Devise` you're going to override its origin mailer methods by:

**config/initializers/devise.rb**

`config.mailer = 'MyOverriddenMailer'`

2. After that, you need to create your overridden mailer class and override whatever method you want like this:

**app/mailers/my_overridden_mailer.rb**

```
class MyOverriddenMailer < Devise::Mailer
  helper :application # gives access to all helpers defined within `application_helper`.
  include Devise::Controllers::UrlHelpers # Optional. eg. `confirmation_url`
  default template_path: 'devise/mailer' # to make sure that you mailer uses the devise views

  def confirmation_instructions(record, token, opts={})
    if record.name.present?
      opts[:subject] = "Welcome #{record.name}, confirm your Qitch.com account"
    else
      opts[:subject] = "Confirm your Qitch.com account"
    end

    super
  end

end
```

3. Remember to restart your Rails server to apply the changes! :)

***Note***:

- List of `opts` options: subject, to, from, reply_to, template_path, template_name.
- `record` is the instance of `User` model
- And of course, [origin document](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3A-Use-custom-mailer)

Comment: This worked for me after reseting my server to load the change in the initializer.

Answer (score 5):

Devise helper [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/mailers/helpers.rb#L28) and [How To: Use custom mailer](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Use-custom-mailer)

```
class MyMailer < Devise::Mailer


   def confirmation_instructions(record, opts={})
    headers = {
        :subject => "Welcome  #{resource.name}, confirm your Qitch.com account"
    }
    super
  end

  def reset_password_instructions(record, opts={})
    headers = {
        :subject => "Welcome  #{resource.name}, reset your Qitch.com password"
    }
    super
  end

  def unlock_instructions(record, opts={})
    headers = {
        :subject => "Welcome  #{resource.name}, unlock your Qitch.com account"
    }
    super
  end

end
```

Or

```
class MyMailer < Devise::Mailer
...
...
private

 def headers_for(action)
  if action == :confirmation_instructions
    headers = {
      :subject => "Welcome  #{resource.name}, confirm your Qitch.com account"
    }
  elsif action == :reset_password_instructions
    headers = {
      :subject => "Welcome  #{resource.name}, reset your Qitch.com password"
    }
  else
    headers = {
      :subject => "Welcome  #{resource.name}, unlock your Qitch.com account"
        }
  end
 end
end
```

And tell devise to use your mailer:

```
#config/initializers/devise.rb
config.mailer = "MyMailer"
```

NOTE : I haven't tried them yet, but they may be helpful and for anyone, please correction my answer, if there is an error you could edit my answer

Comment: Where specifically should I put this custom mailer class? thanks

Comment: corrected : `app/mailers/my_mailer.rb ` @Joseph : have you solve your questions?

Comment: for devise 3.2+ you need `token` argument after `record` and use `opts[:subject] = 'your subject'` to set custom subject.

Answer (score 4):

I'm working with `devise (3.2.1)` and I've implemented the following solution, but to modify the `from:` field with localization:

```
# app/mailers/devise_mailer.rb
class DeviseMailer < Devise::Mailer

  def confirmation_instructions(record, token, opts={})
    custom_options(opts)
    super
  end

  def reset_password_instructions(record, token, opts={})
    custom_options(opts)
    super
  end

  def unlock_instructions(record, token, opts={})
    custom_options(opts)
    super
  end

  private

  def custom_options(opts)
    opts[:from] = I18n.t('devise.mailer.from', name: Tenancy.current_tenancy.name, mail: ENV['FROM_MAILER'] )
  end
end
```

Then I've defined the message in my locale files

```
# config/locales/devise.es.yml
es:
  devise:
    mailer:
      from: "Portal de trabajo %{name} <%{mail}>"
```

To modify the subject, it should be almost the same:

```
  def confirmation_instructions(record, token, opts={})
    custom_options(opts, :confirmation_instructions)
    super
  end

  private

  def custom_options(opts, key)
    opts[:from] = I18n.t('subject', scope: [:devise, :mailer, key])
  end

# and in your locale file
es:
  devise:
    mailer:
      confirmation_instructions:
        subject: Instrucciones de confirmación
```

Answer (score 0):

Hook in `headers_for` to e.g. prefix the subject for all devise mails.

```rb
# config/initializers/devise.rb

Devise.setup do |config|
  # ...
  config.mailer = 'DeviseMailer'
  # ...
end
```

```rb
# app/mailers/devise_mailer.rb

class DeviseMailer < Devise::Mailer
  def headers_for(action, opts)
    super.merge!({ subject: 'Hi ALEX! ' + subject_for(action) })
  end
end
```

Answer (score -2):

Yo should create an ActionMailer like this one:

```
class Sender < ActionMailer::Base
   default :from => "'Eventer' <dfghjk@gmail.com>"

   def send_recover(user, pw)
      mail(:to => user.email , :subject => "You have requested to change your password from Eventer") do |format|
             format.text { 
             render :text =>"Dear #{user.name}, 

                             **Body**

                             Regards."
            }
      end
   end
end
```

Then you should call it from the controller this way:

```
Sender.send_recover(@mail, current_user, @meetup).deliver
```

I hope it works for you!

Regards

Comment: this looks like a generic example about using mailers in rails but the question here is about the best way to override a specific functionality for devise