# Mail chimp with Devise and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailchimp, mandrill, devise-confirmable

I'm trying (failing miserably) to setup mandrill/mailchimp to work with rails 4 and devise.

I'm having loads of trouble using dynamic fields, but now, i can't even insert my logo without mail chimp overriding it to put a black square background behind it.

All I have done is import the image, then when I try to resize it in mailchimp, it imposes a black square background.

Does anyone know how to block this background from being imposed?

Comment: Can you give more details? How are you using Mandrill/Mailchimp? Are you using mergetags to populate content?

Comment: I have set a bounty on my other question to try to find help with merge tags. I've been struggling to figure it out for 1.5 years with this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34821114/rails-4-devise-mandrill-emails. For this current problem, all i do is import an image into mail chimp. All i want to do is resize that image. When I click resize, i type in a new smaller size, and mail chimp imposes a black square background

Comment: Funny, I saw and commented on that post a few days ago... Didn't realize it was 1.5 years old. I'll take another look at it. Anyhow, I've had many, many frustrations with Mandrill/Mailchimp and am now moving on to (hopefully) greener pastures. As for the question you've posed, not sure what this has to do with Devise/Rails this seems to entirely be an issue with Mailchimp.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to fix this black background issue when re-sizing. Same thing happens to me.

Comment: This came from mail chimp support: Also, it's important to mention that because of the lack of a background color for transparent image, a black background is automatically added when the image is edited. Two workarounds would be to resize the image outside of the account in an any outside image editor, or add a white or other colored background, which would enable for that image to be resized in the app and would enable for that black background to not show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This came from mail chimp support: Also, it's important to mention that because of the lack of a background color for transparent image, a black background is automatically added when the image is edited. Two workarounds would be to resize the image outside of the account in an any outside image editor, or add a white or other colored background, which would enable for that image to be resized in the app and would enable for that black background to not show