# custom confirmation mail with dynamic subject in devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, email, authentication, devise

I want to customize devise confirmation mail subject with dynamic content.

I have tried to achieve that by using this [link](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-custom-mailer).

There is no change. It is taking the "Confirmation Instructions" string from devise.en.yml. then I have changed in devise.en.yml file. It has been reflected but anyway It is static change. But I need to change the subject with dynmaic content.

Please guide me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed this issue by creating a subclass of `Devise::Mailer`

```
 class DeviseMailer < Devise::Mailer
   def reset_password_instructions(record, token, opts={})
     mail = super
     # custom logic
     mail.subject = "[Dynamic Subject]"
     mail
   end
 end
```

and customized devise.rb in initializer to call the custom emailer

```
config.mailer = 'DeviseMailer'
```

Comment: Credit for the original answer should go here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21344142/165673